# CodeIgniter Select Query with password function

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select, sql-function

what is the process for using mysql password function in codeIgniter.

my controller

```
$where = array(
        "studentid" => $this->input->post('username'),
        "password" => "password('".$this->input->post('password')."')",
        "status" =>1
    );

    $user = $this->void->getData("users",$where);
```

my model function

```
public function getData($table,$where,$order = 'id')
{
    $this->db->order_by($order);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query=$this->db->get($table);
    return $query->result();
}
```

this is not working. this is generating following query as you can see the problem

```
  SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `studentid` = '054418' AND `password` = 'password(\'054418\')' AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY `id`
```

please help me with solution. thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if it helps:

```
$this->db->where($where, null, false);
```

Try this:

```
$where  = " `studentid` = '".$this->input->post('username')."' AND
            `password`  = password('".$this->input->post('password')."') AND
            `status`    = 1";
```

Comment: i don't know why but 
$this->db->where($where,'',false);
is working.

Comment: in your last part by replacing coma(,) with AND and placing missing ) its working

Comment: By assigning `false`, we tell to not escape the where clause.